# Laravel 10 ide-helper not showing functions

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-10

My PhpStorm is not showing the available methods for `$this->app`. I am expecting it to also show the `$this->app->isProduction()` option.

I have already installed `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` on my PhpStorm 2022.3.2 and Laravel 10.

Why is my PhpStorm not showing the options such as `isProduction()` ?

[image]

If I type it manually, the `isProduction()` is pointing to `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php`. No error reported by phpstorm.

[image]

`$this->app` is pointing to `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php`

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: 1) Will it mark `isProduction()` with a warning etc when typed manually? 2) Will it show that entry if you invoke Code Completion shortcut one more time (normally `Ctrl+Space` on most Windows/Linux keymaps; so it's Ctrl+Space 2x times)

Comment: @LazyOne 1) no warning or error (i updated the question with additional screen shots). 2) pressing `Ctrl+Space` didn't help. Options shown remain the same.

Comment: Would you like to try 2023.1 EAP/Beta build (the next major version to be released in about 2 weeks time) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/ . It may work better there. What's a bit confusing here is the icon used for methods -- it's abstract/interface icons. I do not have any Laravel 10 app here to test it myself, but I do not remember seeing those icons in Laravel 6-8 in older PhpStorm versions. Must be the changes in recent versions that takes interface over actual class (which makes sense overall).